# Why the property of the class implementing the interface not working?

Tags: c#, interface

Kindly, i need to know what i am missing or what i am doing wrong with the following code?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Controls.Add(new B());
        a.Controls.Add(new C());
        a.Controls.Add(new D());
        a.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Edit;
    }
}
public enum DisplayMode
{
    View = 0,
    Edit = 1
}

public interface IMode
{
    DisplayMode DisplayMode { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
    private DisplayMode mDisplayMode;
    public A()
    {
        mDisplayMode = DisplayMode.View;
        Controls = new List<object>();
    }
    public DisplayMode DisplayMode
    {
        get
        {
            return mDisplayMode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mDisplayMode != value)
            {
                mDisplayMode = value;
                foreach (var control in Controls)
                    if (control is IMode)
                        (control as IMode).DisplayMode = value;
                // the control ( b ).DisplayMode is not firing or executing the set
                // what i am missing here?
            }
        }
    }
    public List<object> Controls { get; set; }
}

public class B : IMode
{
    private DisplayMode mDisplayMode;
    public B()
    {
        X=0;
        mDisplayMode=DisplayMode.View;
    }

    public int X { get ; set;}

    public DisplayMode DisplayMode
    {
        get
        {
            return mDisplayMode;
        }
        set
        {
            if (mDisplayMode != value)
            {
                mDisplayMode = value;
                // some code should be executed;
                X=10;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class C {}

public class D {}
```

after i call `a.DisplayMode=DisplayMode.Edit` i am expecting that all controls ( B ) will execute the set of DisplayMode, but after executing the code, its not firing at all

what i mean by the DisplayMode setter value is not executing because if so then X value should become 10

Comment: Are you sure that you have an instance of `B` in the control collection?

Comment: how didn't you get a NullReferenceException with this code? you are not initializing the Controls.Also DisplayMode is an enum and can never be null

Comment: Change your Controls declaration to be `public List<IMode> Controls { get; set; }`

Comment: when i wrote this question i hadn't a compiler because i was trying to explain the problem with a sample code and not running it

Comment: @Rahul your tip will not work because i have other classes C and D which is not implementing the IMode

Comment: @Selman22 i typed the question without testing it, i was trying to point on my problem, thank you for the tip anyway, i edited the question

Comment: Your code seems to work: http://ideone.com/TAYBLX

Comment: i think casting (control as IMode) is the problem but how to solve it?

Comment: @Vlad in the real program the class B is TextBox and C is comboBox and D is DateTime, what i am doing is setting them to read only if in View Mode but they are not working and A is Form

Comment: @Vlad i edited the question again to show you where is the problem, X value is not changing means the B.DisplayMode setter is not firing

Comment: @mah: everything still works fine. Here is your code with some output added: http://ideone.com/F4avKu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as they are saying, your code should work without any problem

can you post your original code, maybe you are missing something that changing the behavior of your code ?

if you insist that the setter is not called then try to call it using reflection, for example

instead of `(control as IMode).DisplayMode`, you can do the following

```
var type=control.GetType();
var property=type.GetProperty("DisplayMode");
property.SetValue(control,value,null);
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should capture an instance of `B` in order to validate, but using your exact code, this works for me:

EDIT: Updated code from OP's sample, where `B` has a property `X` that gets set when `DisplayMode` changes:

```
var a = new A();
var b = new B();

Console.WriteLine("Starting value of b Properties:");
Console.WriteLine(" - b.DisplayMode ... {0}", b.DisplayMode);
Console.WriteLine(" - b.X ............. {0}", b.X);

a.Controls.Add(b);
a.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Edit;

Console.WriteLine("Ending value of b Properties:");
Console.WriteLine(" - b.DisplayMode ... {0}", b.DisplayMode);
Console.WriteLine(" - b.X ............. {0}", b.X);    

// Ouput:
// Starting value of b Properties:
//  - b.DisplayMode ... View
//  - b.X ............. 0
// Ending value of b Properties:
//  - b.DisplayMode ... Edit
//  - b.X ............. 10
```

Comment: sure it will work but the setter inside B will not executed because other code should be executed, for example kindly add property integer called X and by default X=0 and when the setter of B should max X=10; at the end you will find b.DisplayMode changed and X still 0

Comment: @mah That's not correct...the setter gets called (how else would the value get set?), and X is updated. I've updated my sample based on your latest code change.

Answer (score 0):

1/ First you should instantiate the List.

2/ Are you sure that mDisplayMode != value?
I mean when you set display mode to "edit" on A, perhaps it's already its value.